# how should I troubleshoot why my databinding expressions aren't being bound or altered?

Tags: angularjs

Given some simple markup like so:

```
div(ng-model="chart")
...
div.configureChart
  h5 Configure Chart 
  h4 {{name}}
```

If I'm getting `{{name}}` on the page instead, what techniques can I utilize to figure out why my binding isn't connecting? Some of my databinding is working, so the app is set up correctly in at least some cases.

I'm not looking for the solution to this problem; rather I'd like a troubleshooting checklist for situations where things ought to be bound but don't seem to be working. Angular's lack of error messages makes sorting out problems difficult.

Comment: i would recommend you using angular bartrang extension available with chrome store to troubleshoot angular binding problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is pretty old and doesn't have any answers so...

The solution that I came up with was to have a function called ngscope that's global:

```
function (selector) {
      return angular.element(selector).scope();
    }
```

Then you can use "Inspect Element" in Chrome and run ngscope($0) to get the scope of the object you inspected. That helps a lot, you can see what the scope looks like *for that object*. Batarang works too, but I found that I preferred the command line version. Sometimes Batarang got in the way.